# Somebody could help me telling what kind of list is it in Android? (new in Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-cardview

sorry for the question but I'm new in Android.

I would like to put on my app the list exactly showed below. It is a list with many horizontal list on it and for every horizontal list there is a description e.g "Most visited attractions" and a button "SEE ALL" which on clicking show the entire list on another screen.

I tried looking on the internet, but didn't succeed 'cause I don't know exactly what kind of list it is.

Cheers!

[image]

Comment: cardview with nested RecyclerView..

Comment: Thanks, mate! I really appreciate your reply! Cheers!

Comment: You can do this with simple listview also by attaching your created custom layouts.

Comment: Sweet! Glad to know there's another option. Thanks again!

Comment: @AmitVaghela, Thank you so much, mate! This is what I was looking for!! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please visit this github library [MaterialLeanBack](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialLeanBack)

Here, you have to make a control for button you are placing will show full screen after click.

**Usage**

```
<com.github.florent37.materialleanback.MaterialLeanBack
        android:id="@+id/materialLeanBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:mlb_background="@color/background"
        app:mlb_lineSpacing="30dp"

        app:mlb_paddingBottom="30dp"
        app:mlb_paddingLeft="30dp"
        app:mlb_paddingRight="30dp"
        app:mlb_paddingTop="40dp"

        app:mlb_titleColor="@android:color/white" />
```

**Download**

```
compile 'com.github.florent37:materialleanback:1.0.0@aar'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
```

[image]

Comment: Already did, mate, but when I tried to vote stackoverflow says I need to earn 15 points reputation before doing this! Sorry for that and thanks, again!

Comment: Done, @Amit Vaghela! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for appriciation @RafaelPaz